# Solving the following nonlinear differential equation: $x=2tx'-3(x')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me solving the following differential equation? $$x=2tx'-3(x')^2$$

I have tried to solve it by first taking the derivative of the given equation and then replacing $u=x'$. But I couldn't solve it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation

Comment: @CTSnake This is not a Clairaut Equation. However, it is a [d'Alembert Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsEquation.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must solve:
$$x=2t\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}-3\cdot \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 \tag{1}$$
Your idea to take the derivative with respect to $t$ and then substituting $u=x'(t)$ is a good one.

---

**Verification of your attempt:**

I'll leave this section so that you can verify your attempt. This is a [d'Alembert equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsEquation.html). Start by differentiating both sides wrt $t$:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2t\cdot \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}+2\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}-6\cdot \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$$
One can write this as:
$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{2(3\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}-t)}$$
Now, substitute $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ (By preference, I'll use $v$ instead of $u$). Therefore, we obtain:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{v}{2(3v-t)}$$
Based on what you listed as an attempt, I assume here is as far as you got. If you did not get this on your attempt so far, please try again.

---

**The trick:**

If you take the reciprocal on both sides, this gives a first order linear ODE:
$$\frac{dt}{dv}=\frac{2(3v-t)}{v} \iff \frac{dt}{dv}+\frac{2}{v}\cdot t=6 \tag{2}$$
Equation $(2)$ can be solved using an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

---

I'll leave you to derive the solution to $(2)$. The solution should be:

> $$t(v)=2v+\frac{C}{v^2} \tag{3}$$

Now, substitute back to obtain:
$$t=2\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{C}{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2} \tag{4}$$
Using the quadratic formula, solving for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ in the original equation $(1)$ gives:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}(t\pm \sqrt{t^2-3x})$$
Substitute this into $(4)$ and simplify to obtain the general solution.

Note that this will be an **implicit solution**. I don't think it is possible to obtain an explicit solution for $x(t)$.